# Timestamp changes in Firestore SDK for nodeJS (possibly elsewhere as well)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Updating my nodeJS packages for my Google Cloud Run, I realized that Google seemed to have changed the Firestore SDK with some breaking changes concerning Timestamp.

(not quite sure at what exact minor-version update this happened).

Here is my findings so far (see below).

Can somebody please comment what the recommended way to go is ???

before:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.9.0"
  },
```

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
const timestamp = firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
```

The above code worked fine until before my package update.

Some people write that since v11 there is the following approach:

new since  "firebase-admin": "^11.11.x"

```
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
const timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Data());
```

However, this code crashes with the follwoing error:

> Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Detected an object of type "Timestamp" that doesn't match the expected instance.

Most likely the way to go ???????

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^7.1.0",
  },
```

```
import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
const timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Data());
```

Please put some light on the recommended way to go. Thank you.

---

In more detail:

The firestore-update crashes. And the reason is the `changedAt` property.

If I use `firebase-admin` (11.9.0 or 11.11.1) then the update crases !! If I use `@google-cloud/firestore` then it works !!!

```
async updateApi(
  trucId: String,
): Promise<Truc | undefined> {
  const truc: Truc = await this.findTruc(trucID);

  let updateTruc = truc;
  
  updateTruc.changedAt = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
  
  // filter out fields with undefined values from the updateTruc
  for (const key in updateTruc) {
    if (updateTruc[key] === undefined) {
      delete updateTruc[key];
    }
  }

  // Update the Firestore document with the updateTruc fields
  await this.update({ ...truc, ...updateTruc });
  
  return updateTruc;
}
```

I am using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com) and [Fireorm](https://fireorm.js.org/#/) to find and update the Objects:

```
@Injectable()
export class TrucsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Truc)
    private trucs: BaseFirestoreRepository<Truc>,
  ) {}


  async findTruc(id: string): Promise<Truc> {
    return await this.trucs
      .whereEqualTo((t) => t.id, id)
      .whereEqualTo((t) => t.active, true)
      .whereEqualTo((t) => t.deleted, false)
      .findOne();
  }

  async update(truc: Truc): Promise<Truc> {
    return await this.trucs.update(truc);
  }
}
```

The Truc Object in NestJS follows:

```
import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore'; // WORKS !
// import { Timestamp } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';  // DOES NOT WORK (v11.11.1)

@Collection('trucs')
export class Trucs {
  id!: string;
  active: boolean;
  deleted: boolean;
  changedAt: Timestamp;
}
```

Until the package update, this code was working (but not anymore):

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin'; // WORKED with 11.9.0

@Collection('trucs')
export class Trucs {
  id!: string;
  active: boolean;
  deleted: boolean;
  changedAt: firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your quoted error message could be generated from the code you show here.  Are you missing a call to `update()` somewhere to update a document, as the message seems to indicate?

Comment: yes you are right - I forgot to place the "update" calling code. Please see in original post above....

Comment: Can you distill this example down to the complete, minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem? There are several variables we can't see here, including the contents of `truc`, which could also cause the problem.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves to observe the same problem. Maybe also add some logging for the value you're trying to insert so we can all see what it is.

Comment: I am adding stuff (not easy since I need to cut out things first...)

Comment: this is the very minimum of code that shows the full example (see botom part of original post)

Comment: We don't really need to see the definitions of everything.  We need to see the one line of code with hard-coded data that causes the failure (that's what is meant by "minimal" in [MCRE](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)).  A single field on a single document should do.  We should be able to copy that and run it for ourselves to see the problem. Try writing a standalone node.js program for that.

Comment: The one line of code that crashes is `await this.update({ ...truc, ...updateTruc });`

Comment: firebase-admin 10.9.0 does not crash when  `updateTruc.changedAt = firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

Comment: firebase-admin 11.11.1 crashes when `updateTruc.changedAt = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

Comment: Right, and I'm saying we can't see the contents of `truc`, as that could also cause a problem.  Remove as much code as you can and focus on the one field alone that causes the problem.

Comment: @google-cloud/firestore 7.1.0 does NOT CRASH when `updateTruc.changedAt = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

Comment: content of `truc` does not matter at all !  It is a completely normal object. And I stripped it down to  having only 3 properties (active, deleted and changedAt). Whereas the changedAt-date causes the crash (...depending on which way I create the date)

Comment: The update method of `BaseFirestoreRepository` of `fireorm` cannot deal with a date that is created with 'firebase-admin' anymore.  (`update(item: T): Promise<T>;` can only handle Timestamps from `@google-cloud/firestore` - but no longer `firebase-admin` v11.11.1.    It was able to do it with firebase-admin v10.9.0 - but not with v11.11.1 anymore. So clearly, the `firebase-admin` SDK added an incompatibility for dates (with respect to `fireorm` updates.  I will put this in the `fireorm` forum as well.

Comment: see https://github.com/wovalle/fireorm/issues/328